# What are some intuitive and easy examples of Compact Operators?

Tags: operator-theory, compact-operators

Just like you can understand the adjoint operator as the transpose of a matrix, or the normal operator as $z \overline{z} = \overline{z} z$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, how can I understand the compact operator on an easy example?

I can't seem to find any easy and intuitive examples on that. I've heard something about the integral (operators) being compact (why?), but that's all I know.

Comment: All bounded linear operators with finite rank are compact so you won't find an illuminating way of illustrating what it means to be compact in the language of matrices. For lots of spaces (those with the approximation property) including all Hilbert spaces, any compact operator is even a limit of finite rank operators.

Comment: Compact operators are the closest thing to (infinite dimensional) matrices. Important finite-dimensional linear algebra results apply to them. The most important one: Self-adjoint compact operators on a Hilbert space (typically, integral operators) can be diagonalized using a discrete sequence of eigenvectors.

Comment: Integral operators are compact because of general compactness criteria (in $L^2$, you need to check boundedness, equicontinuity and uniform $L^2$-integrability, for instance, iirc; in $C^0$ you can use Ascoli). They’re among my favorite examples of compact operators. Another class of examples, rather related, is Sobolev embeddings, see the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem (added regularity lets you find convergent subsequences).

Comment: "you won't find an illuminating way of illustrating what it means to be compact in the language of matrices" so is there maybe another way to illustrate it, if not in the language of matrices?

Comment: "Compact operators are the closest thing to (infinite dimensional) matrices" this sounds very interesting, in which way are they the "closest" thing to infinite dimensional matrices? Could you maybe elaborate this on an example?

Comment: @StefanLafon "Compact operators are the closest thing to (infinite dimensional) matrices" - That's false, sorry. You can represent any bounded operator on a separable Hilbert space as an infinite matrix. Compact operators are the closest thing to finite-rank operators, but that's what I told OP already in another MSE post.

Comment: I stand corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an easy example? Ok, there you go. The operator $T : \ell^2(\mathbb N)\to\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, defined by
$$
(Tx)_n = \frac 1n\cdot x_n,\quad x\in\ell^2(\mathbb N),
$$
is a compact operator. You can represent it as an infinite diagonal matrix with the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ on its diagonal.

Compact operators are an important class of bounded operators. They are important because

- they often appear in the analysis of operators
- they have many remarkable properties and they are well understood.

So, the knowledge on compact operators often helps in the understanding of structures. The set of compact operators that are not finite-rank is just on the edge between the finite-dimensional and the infinite-dimensional world, where topology becomes more important.

Comment: Interesting. May be a naive question, but are all matrices compact? If not, which are, and which aren't?

Comment: What I'm trying to ask all the time is for a relation between Compact Operators and a already familiar topic/object in mathematics. Just like adjoint operators are related to transpose matrices, or normal operators are related to complex numbers: To what kind of thing are compact operators related to?

Comment: How would you describe the real numbers? Say, the rational numbers are known.

Comment: Well, at some point mathematics becomes more advanced so that things cannot be compared or described easily by using more simple notions. Please accept that. I added a sentence to my answer.